# How to add a homepage link in my about firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like the user to be able to view a hyperlink to my website when he clicks  on my addon from tools , addon. So how would i exactly  add a hyperlink to my site. I am using firefox addon sdk.[image]

Edit:

I realized the icon could be changed with icon:"name.png" in packages.json. But is there a similar way to change the homepage URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `package.json` by adding a `homepage` property like this:

```
{
"name": "myaddons", 
"license": "MPL 2.0", 
"author": "", 
"version": "0.1", 
"fullName": "myaddons", 
"id": "jid1-TGV1ZHqyB9PkVg", 
"description": "a basic add-on",
"homepage": "http://examples.com",
"icon": "chrome://myext/skin/icon.png"
}
```

and then run `cfx xpi`.

These values are used by `install.rdf`.

[More info](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.7/dev-guide/package-spec.html)

Comment: I dont have an install.rdf, I am using firefoxaddonsdk

Comment: Yes. But if i edit the install.rdf in it and hit cfx xpi it says packages.json not found. If i simple unzip the xpi edit the install.rdf and zip it back it says the addon is corrupt and cannot be loaded.